# Redirect (301) from domain.com to www.domain.com, while also forcing HTTPS in HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, https, http-status-code-301

Ok, so this is what I have originally , which redirects any domain.net or www.domain.net to www.domain.com (with SSL).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Now, I want to force all of these conditions to report 301 to (for search engine purposes):
domain.net
www.domain.net
domain.com

and force all conditions to:
www.domain.com WITH SSL  (even somebody typing http://www.domain.com should reach https://www.domain.com).

Does that make sense?  Here's what I've got so far, which I think will work, but I don't know how to add in the 301 part...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: change the `[R,L]` to `[R=301,L]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want to use only www.domain.com, but you code says you only want to use domain.com. Anyway, this should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect any domain other than www.domain.com to www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# force https on www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You're right, that was a typo.  However, this doesn't account for the situation where I go to `http://www.domain.com/whatever.php?id=23` - I would want this to simply add the `S` to the `http` - in your case it's sending them back to the root domain.

Comment: @Shackrock - Actually this should work, note the $ at the end of the statement.