# my 301 redirect from https to https doesn't work

Tags: redirect

I have found a few [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770545/redirect-301-from-domain-com-to-www-domain-com-while-also-forcing-https-in-ht) [requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164590/is-it-okay-to-send-a-301-redirect-from-https-if-not-in-use) here that explain this, but mine is slightly different and I still can't get my head around it. Sorry, am new user, so I have to fuddle with the example urls because I'm only allowed two.

I have a domain with SSL cert: **https colon // mysubdomain.myfullurl dotcom**
I also have a domain **without** SSL: **http colon // mysubdomain.mfu dotcom**

Someone has erroneously printed material with:
**https colon // mysubdomain.mfu dotcom/somefolder/**
which should really go to:
**https colon // mysubdomain.myfullurl dotcom/somefolder/**

My client has advised me to do a 301 redirect for this link, and all traffic at mfu.com. But can I do a 301 on an https that doesn't actually have the SSL cert?

This is the entire contents of my htaccess file, and nothing else is in the server directory:

```
# Redirect mysubdomain.mfu.com to
# mysubdomain.myfullurl.com
Redirect 301 / https://mysubdomain.myfullurl.com/
```

At a url checker, it can only check http redirects (not https), but when I check the url it shows a 302, not 301 redirect.